# How to get an image from xml data by parsing

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I have an xml structure like this

```
 <element>
   <foodjoint_name>DineOut</foodjoint_name>
   <logo>http://192.168.1.112/dineout/images/dominos.jpg</logo>
 </element>
```

I am parsing the data : `<foodjoint_name>` will be a string name of some thing 
`<logo >` will be an image url . I have a xmlParser where i am parsing the data

In my main class, I am showing in a `listView` the parsed data. My problem is that, I am not getting the logo.

How to get that ?  Please tell me, if i have to change in code.

This is my main class

```
// All static variables

    static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.112/dineout/index.php/dineout/view";

    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "element"; // parent node
    //static final String KEY_ID = "foodjoint_id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "foodjoint_name";
    static final String KEY_LOGO = "logo";
    //static final String KEY_DESC = "foodjoint_description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            //map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_LOGO,  parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOGO));

            //map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_LOGO }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name,R.id.imageView1 });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_LOGO, cost);
                //in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my parser class

```
public class XMLParser {



    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following URL will help you to get the answer for your question
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: your welcome divaNilisha But sorry but i dont know how to add any1 in chat since i m still learning how to use stackoverflow

Comment: Also i am working so don't get enough time to be in chat room of stackoverflow.

Comment: same here..... okay if i have any problem futher i will mention you here in comment . As sometimes i am in very urgent need of answer , cannot wait at that time. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to do http request for the image saperately isn't it??

Do the http request and save the image on sdcard and then use that sdcard path to show it in your imageview..

Comment: No , i am getting the http request, parsing it into xml , one of its node has the value as image path how to do so ?

Comment: that is what i am saying after all the parsing has done.. you will get the image path like this.. "http://192.168.1.112/dineout/images/dominos.jpg".. then after parsing do the http request on this path, you will get image in bitmap which you can use it for showing it

Answer (score 0):

For parsing xml use [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). Once the url is fetched you can download it easily.

Comment: could you please give me an example? i have not tried it before, how to use that

Comment: the link i have mentioned here contains the example.